# Directory excluding in sonar-project.properties file doesn't work (for me)

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have excluded the directory in my project properties but sonar doesn't exclude it. Can anyone help me to find problem?

```
sonar.sources=./ 
sonar.exclusions=./utility/Excel/**
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I realized that first I should have written directory name Like below to exclude all folders and file on that directory:

```
 sonar.exclusions=utility/Excel/**/*
```

Second I should have used comma separated directory names to exclude more than one directory:

```
 sonar.exclusions=utility/Excel/**/* , utility/mailer/**/*
```

Comment: thanks for the comma separation information. It saved me a day.

Comment: ok I just wanna throw out that it's really confusing `sonar.sources` uses path relative to sonar-project.properties, and apparently `sonar.exclusions` doesn't? ugh took me forever. thanks, never would have tried that

Comment: how to exclude multiple files?

Answer (score 37):

Look at the [Inclusions/Exclusions Patterns documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) , and try this: `sonar.exclusions=utility/Excel/**`.

Note: pointing *sonar.sources* to the current directory is usually a mistake, you should point it to the actual directories which contain the sources (more details in [Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/)).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not your own post answered 5 days later and explained stuff which wasn't even part of the question.

Comment: The provided links are currently broken.